# how to add raw resources to a react-native native android library

Tags: android, react-native

I've created a native library and I'm using it in my react-native application but I'd like to add a raw resource (sound file) to the library.  I tried just adding a res/raw directory with the file but it doesn't seem to generate an R.java file for the build.  How is this done?